# 'Bad Request' with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

Windows 10, Codeigniter 3, Wamp3.

Ajax post throws a Bad Request error. This is an old chestnut but online research shows the problem usually to be CSRF. However I emphasize at the outset that I have csrf disabled for this test:

```
config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

I have set up some deliberately very simple test code. The controller looks like this:

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {


$this->load->view('pages/index');
}

public function hello($name) {
    $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
    echo 'Hello '.$fullname;

}

}//EOF
```

and the view looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo Ajax</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#bttHello').click(function(){
            var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {fullname: fullname},
                url:'<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello'); ?> + fullname',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#result1').html(result);

                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

Name <input type="text" id="fullname">
<input type="button" value="Hello" id="bttHello">
<br>
<span id="result1"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

The console shows a Bad Request

```
POST XHR http://localhost/faith/ajax/hello%20+%20fullname [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 9ms]
```

So if csrf is not the culprit, is it a Wamp issue? Everything else seems to work fine. I have spent so much time on this!
What is going on?

Comment: You should check your server error log for the actual error instead of trying to guess the problem.

Comment: First of all you using ajax post then why you are sending data params attach with url. No need post data is enough to send params to controller method. Secondly hello param has name param required then what you expecting by just normal post. Third the param you getting from ajax is well then what name param doing inside those beautiful parenthsis. If its optional param make them optional. Remove param from ajax url and make method param optional in method. You good to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data are already sent through `POST`. No need to pass it through URL

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#bttHello').click(function(){
    var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data: {fullname: fullname},
      url:"<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello'); ?>",
      success: function(result) {
        $('#result1').html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And, remove parameter `$name` from controller action `hello()`.

```
public function hello() {
  $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
  echo 'Hello '.$fullname;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - many thanks! Now I have another problem because when I enable csrf I want to get the value from a cookie, but jquery.cookie.js is not working for me...

Comment: @Perkin5: I wish I could've helped you regarding new issue. But, I've not worked in codeigniter before. So, I'll not divert you from the path. I'll suggest you to ask another question regarding CSRF issue. *Please, don't mind.*

Answer (score 0):

write url like this

```
"url": "<?php echo base_url().'ajax/hello';?>/" + fullname
```

after `/fullname` its a `argument` of `function hello()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    <?php echo form_open('ajax/hello', [
            'method' => 'post',
            'class' => 'create_form'
        ]); ?>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Full Name"/>
<button type="submit">Create</button>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.create_form', function (e) {
            var self = this;
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(self).attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

***The CodeIgniter Controller:***

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/index');
    }
    /**
     * @param $name
     */
    public function hello($name)
    {
        // if no $name params value pass and post exist
        if ( ! isset($name) && $this->input->post('fullname')) {
            // get value from post params
            $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname', true);
        } elseif (isset($name) && ! $this->input->post('fullname')) {
            // get value from pass param method
            $fullname = $name;
        } else {
            // default value
            $fullname = 'No Name found';
        }
        // show ajax response
        echo $fullname;
    }
    /**
     * Another way if we using GET params
     * e.g. http://wwww.site.com/ajax/hello/my-name-value
     * @param $name
     */
    public function hello_another($name)
    {
        // if url has param as name value
        // remember codeigniter will map all url params as method params as they provided
        // no need to use get input, it will take from url string directly
        if (isset($name)) {
            // get value from get params
            $fullname = $name;
        } else {
            // default value
            $fullname = 'No Name found';
        }
        // show ajax response
        echo $fullname;
    }
    /**
     * Another way if we using GET params and security is on top
     * e.g. http://wwww.site.com/ajax/hello/my-name-value
     * @param $name
     */
    public function hello_another_secure($name)
    {
        // if url has param as name value
        // remember codeigniter will map all url params as method params as they provided
        // no need to use get input, it will take from url string directly
        if (isset($name) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $name)) {
            // get value from method params
            $fullname = $name;
        } else {
            // default value
            $fullname = 'No Name or invalid name found';
        }
        // show ajax response
        echo $fullname;
    }
}
//EOF
```

---

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#bttHello').click(function(){
            var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {fullname: fullname},
                url:'<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello'); ?>',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#result1').html(result);

                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

---

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#bttHello').click(function(){
            var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello_another/'); ?> + fullname',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#result1').html(result);

                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

*The CodeIgniter is fully capable to fulfil your needs, Just look their [AWESOME Document](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) first..*

Answer (score -2):

```
use this way
you should concate fullname variable after quatation.
like this
url:'<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello'); ?>' + fullname


<script>
$(function() {
    $('#bttHello').click(function(){
        var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: {fullname: fullname},
            url:'<?php echo base_url('ajax/hello'); ?>' + fullname,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#result1').html(result);

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: "*..use this way*". Can You Please Explain Why OP Will Use This Answer. Every Answer Needs Explanation.